# How can modify request.data in django REST framework

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django REST Framework

```
request.data = '{"id": "10", "user": "tom"}'
```

I want to add extra attribute like `"age": "30"` before sending it to further like

```
    request.data = new_data
    response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I have two issues

1. Why `request.data` is coming as string rather than `dict`
2. How can I update the `request.data`

Comment: Please give a bit more context such as how you add the extra attribute and why do you want to update the request.data. Note that updating request.data is usually a bit idea.

Comment: @Linovia  i want to add extra attribute  `request.data['age'] = 30`. now i can't do that as request.data is string not dict. now if use `data = json.loads(request.data)` then `request.data = json_data` then i get error  not able to set attribute on request

Comment: Adding "request.data['age'] = 30" is how you are trying to do something, not the reason why you want to do/need that.

Comment: @Linovia because  before posting i need to chnage the field names aqs required by the API , so i need to chnage the request data

Answer (score 19):

In case your API is `APIView` then you should use update function to expand your request data object without losing the data sent from the client-side.

```
request.data.update({"id": "10", "user": "tom"})
```

Comment: AttributeError: This QueryDict instance is immutable

Comment: @AlexanderP add "request.data._mutable = True" and it will work.

Answer (score 17):

`request.data` should be an immutable [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects), rather than a string.  If you need to modify it:

```python
if isinstance(request.data, QueryDict):  # optional
    request.data._mutable = True
request.data["age"] = "30"
```

The only reason you might check if it's an instance of `QueryDict` is so it's easier to unit test with a regular `dict`.

Answer (score 8):

A good friend just took me to school on a much simpler approach than I illustrate above

```
class CreateSomething(CreateAPIView):
    model = Something
    queryset = Something.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SomethingSerializer

    perform_create(self,serializer):
    def perform_create(self,serializer):
        ip = self.get_ip()
        ## magic here: add kwargs for extra fields to write to db
        serializer.save(ip_addr=ip)

    def get_ip(self):
        x_forwarded_for = self.request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',None)
        if x_forwarded_for:
            ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
        else:
            ip = self.request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR',None)
        return ip

class SomethingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=Something.objects.all())])
    fieldA = serializers.CharField()
    fieldB = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Customer2
        fields = ['email','fieldA','fieldB','ip_addr']
        read_only_fields = ['ip_addr']
```

Comment: It's so sad that there isn't a more intuitive way to do this. Probably a better mixin or some predefined function.

Comment: @Altus, there are ways to do that, or you mean djangoish ways?

Comment: This is not a "much simpler approach" at all.

Answer (score 8):

Generally `request` in drf views is `rest_framework.request.Request` instance. Following to it's source code (`djangorestframework==3.8.2`):

```py
    @property
    def data(self):
        if not _hasattr(self, '_full_data'):
            self._load_data_and_files()
        return self._full_data
```

You can do:

```py
request._full_data = your_data
```

Comment: FYI accessing private methods or attributes is a really bad idea, but if you've got no other options you "can" do that.

Answer (score 3):

If your endpoint is implemented with a DRF (Django REST Framework) `ViewSet` the solution can be to implement the corresponding serializer class's `to_internal_value` method and modify the data there.

```
class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = ...
    ...
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer


class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('id', 'user', ...)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        instance = super(MyModelSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
        if "lastModified" in data:
            # instance["id"] = 10  # That's sketchy though
            instance["user"] = "tom"
        return instance
```

Comment: BTW, you can also make some manipulations if you override the `ModelViewSet`'s `create` and `update` methods.

Comment: where "to_internal_value" method called?

Comment: @isifzade it is called by the DRF framework as part of the deserialization workflow of the object. See related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34196331/usage-of-to-representation-and-to-internal-value-in-django-rest-framework and https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a json string. To convert it to a dict you should do:

```
import json
data = json.loads(request.data)
```

then you can add extra attributes:

```
data['age'] = 30
```

Then you will have to make a new request because it seem like you cant just change the old one. This assumes that you are posting to /notes/:

```
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory
factory = APIRequestFactory()
request = factory.post('/notes/', data, format='json')
```

Comment: if i use `request.data = json_data` it says not able to set attribute on request

Comment: Yikes... although this works, DRF should have a cleaner way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are afraid of altering your request object, then use deep copy to copy the object and then you can easily alter it.

Usage::

```
from copy import deepcopy

# here is your other code and stuffs
data = deepcopy(request.data)
```

feel free to alter the data as you want as it is now mutable.

So far, this is my preferred way of altering if not using a generic view.

For any drawbacks of this method, please comment below!

Answer (score 1):

Though other answers are good but i just wanted to add one thing here;

We have now two ways to update a `request.data` object But before that, check if it is a QueryDict (as already mentioned by @mikebridge);

```
from django.http.request import QueryDict


if isInstance(request.data, QueryDict):
    request.data._mutable = True
```

After that, to update the request.data, first way is;

```
request.data.update({'key': 'new_value'})
```

this will work fine, but say if the request.data['key'] which you want to update is a list, then the value will not get changed completely by the `new_value` but it will get appended to the older list which may cause trouble and you may not get the desired result.

So to overcome that, i.e, to completely change the value of some key, use the second method;

```
request.data['key'] = 'new_value'
```

This will change the value of `request.data['key']` completely to `new_value`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment:

> "because before posting i need to chnage the field names aqs required by the API"

You should be using the `Field`'s [`source` argument](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) instead.

This will make error messages more consistent otherwise your user will face errors with field names they didn't provide.

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this differently. I override the CreateAPIView create method, as follows

```
class IPAnnotatedObject(CreateAPIView):
    model = IPAnnotatedObject
    queryset = IPAnnotatedObject.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IPAnnotatedObject
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data['ip_addr'] = self.get_ip()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        ## perform_create calls serializer.save() which calls the serializer's create() method
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def get_ip(self):
        x_forwarded_for = self.request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',None)
        if x_forwarded_for:
            ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
        else:
            ip = self.request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR',None)
        return ip
```

The corresponding serializer class looks like follows

```
class IPAnnotatedObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=IPAnnotatedObject.objects.all())])
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    ip_addr = serializers.IPAddressField(write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = IPAnnotatedObject
        fields = ['email','password','created_ip']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        email, password, created_ip = validated_data['email'], validated_data['password'],validated_data['created_ip']
        try:
            ipAnnoObject = IPAnnotatedObject.objects.create(email=email,password=make_password(password),ip_addr=ip_addr)
        except Exception as e:
            # you can think of better error handler
            pass
        return ipAnnoOjbect
```

Comment: The best way to alter in a generic view is to override get_serializer method... 

This is a bit redundant as your serializer is not working at all if you are helpin it create

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```py
import json

data = json.dumps(request.data)
data = json.loads(data)

data['age'] = 100
```

now use variable `data` instead of `request.data`.

Answer (score 0):

May be override `is_valid` in your serializer class will be more readable

```
class YourSerializer
    
    # Don't forget it
    age = serializers.IntegerField()

    def is_valid(self, raise_exception: bool = ...) -> bool:
        self.initial_data["age"] = 30
        return super().is_valid(raise_exception)
```