# Usage of .to_representation() and .to_internal_value in django-rest-framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

What do `.to_representation()` and `.to_internal_value` do in `serializers`?
If I pass data to a serializer, is the data thrown `to_representation()` first?
What's the usage of these two?

Answer (score 31):

> If you want to create a custom field, you'll need to subclass Field
>   and then override either one or both of the `.to_representation()` and
>   `.to_internal_value()` methods. These two methods are used to convert
>   between the initial datatype, and a primitive, serializable datatype.
>   Primitive datatypes will typically be any of a number, string,
>   boolean, date/time/datetime or None. They may also be any list or
>   dictionary like object that only contains other primitive objects.
>   Other types might be supported, depending on the renderer that you are
>   using.
>
> The `.to_representation()` method is called to convert the initial
>   datatype into a primitive, serializable datatype.
>
> The `to_internal_value()` method is called to restore a primitive
>   datatype into its internal python representation. This method should
>   raise a serializers.ValidationError if the data is invalid.
>
> Note that the `WritableField` class that was present in version 2.x no
>   longer exists. You should subclass Field and override
>   `to_internal_value()` if the field supports data input.

Ref:

1. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields
2. https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L417

Comment: lol  this is already mentioned in the doc.

Comment: Yes that's what mentioned in reference links.

Comment: Since the OP asked for serializers and not fields, I want to add that in serializers the `to_internal_value` does the same returning an `OrderedDict` of native values. It does that by running validators for every field. The method is called in `Serializer.run_validation`.